# How to get a pointer to a 2D std::vector's contents

Tags: c++, stdvector

Given

```
std::vector<char> theVec
```

I can get the pointer as follows

```
char* cc = &theVec[0]
```

What if the vector is declared as follows:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char> > theVec
```

How do you get a pointer to the head of theVec into a char*

```
char cc* =
```

Answer (score 4):

> How do you get a pointer to the head of theVec [as a char*]?

You can't. The head of your vector is of type `std::vector<char>`, not `char`, and a `std::vector<std::vector<char> >` doesn't store its data in one contiguous block.

Instead, you can do this:

```
std::vector<char> theVec;
theVec.resize(xSize*ySize);
char cc* = &theVec[0];
char tmp = theVec[x*xSize + y];//instead of theVec[x][y]
```

Comment: You show ho to access an element in the 2D vector but how would you populate this vector? I have a hard time visualizing how the this cannot be anything but a one dimension array

Comment: Vectors typically are one-dimensional arrays, but you forget they're also classes, and Joe specified *contiguous*. I'm not sure where `std::vector` does its book-keeping, but it's likely before the data array, so you'll have some gaps with 2D vectors.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<char> * p = &theVec[0];
```

If you want a pointer to the first char, then:

```
char * p = &theVec[0][0];
```

However, be careful, because iterating that pointer past the first sub-vector will not move it into the next vector like would happen with a multidimensional array.  To get a pointer to the head of the next sub-vector, you would use:

```
p = &theVec[1][0];
```

Comment: No I want to get the vector's content into a char *